# Resize image in grid to fit div to smaller size

Tags: css

I am trying to build a header with 3 columns. One image in each column. 
I need the images to resize to fit the height of the header.

My images have 100px x 100px resolution.

So with heights higher than 100px the resizing is working fine:

[image]

But with with heights smaller than 100px the image is not resizing.

[image]

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="headergridelement"><img alt="" src="file:///C:/.../info100x100.jpg"></div>
        <div class="headergridelement"><img alt="" src="file:///C:/.../info100x100.jpg"></div>
        <div class="headergridelement"><img alt="" src="file:///C:/.../info100x100.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is the css I am using.

```
#header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height:100%;
}

#header .headergridelement {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#header img {
    height:100%;
}


body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

What property I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `object-fit: cover` and then specify the `max-height` you need, that is 100% in this case.
So, it prevents the image from overflowing the `#header` element.

```
#header img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

You can take a look about `object-fit` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) at MDN docs.

### Update: solution 2

The code above works fine in Chrome browser, but doesn't work in Firefox.
A solution for Firefox would be to use `position: relative` in the parent div and `position: absolute` in the image. In addition, set `height: 100%` and position and margin to center the image.

```
#header .headergridelement {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
   position: relative;
}
```

```
#header img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Not resolving the problem

Comment: Oh, I see. In Firefox it is not working. Just a sec.